# Applying Logic to Grouped SQL Results

Tags: sql, oracle

Looking for some Oracle SQL theoretical help on the best way to handle a grouped result set.  I understand why it groups the way it does, but I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to

I have a table that lists the activity of some cost centers.  It looks like this:

```
Company    Object    Sub    July    August
A          1                20      50
A          1                10      0
A          1         10     0       20
B          1                0       0
```

I then need to flag whether or not there was activity in August.  So I'm writing a CASE statement where if August = 0 THEN 'FALSE' ELSE 'TRUE'.  Then I need to group all records by Company, Object, and Sub.  The Cumulative column is a SUM of both July and August.  However, my output looks like this:

```
Company    Object    Sub    SUM    ActivityFlag
A          1                70        TRUE
A          1                10        FALSE
A          1         10     20        TRUE
B          1                0         FALSE
```

What I need is this:

```
Company    Object    Sub    August    ActivityFlag
A          1                80        TRUE
A          1         10     20        TRUE
B          1                0         FALSE
```

Obviously, this is a simplified example of a much larger issue, but I'm trying to think through this problem theoretically so I can apply similar logic to my actual issue.

Is there a good SQL method for adding the August amount for rows 1 and 2, and then selecting TRUE so that this appears on a single row?  I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use aggregation

```
select company,object,sub,sum(july+august),
max(case when august>0 then 'True' else 'false' end)
from table_name group by company,object,sub
```

Comment: I think the case check is only supposed to be against `august>0`, not `(july+august)>0`? (Also need the string case needs to match for max to work properly, possibly depending on language/collation; but that's a minor detail *8-)

Comment: Correct, the case statement only flags for True or False if activity occurred in August only, but all months (July and August) should be calculated on the final output.

Answer (score 1):

If you are flagging your detail with the case statement you can either put the case in a sum similar to:

```
MAX(CASE WHEN August = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

Another way if to aggregate the flag upward in an inner query:

```
SELECT IsAugust = MAX(IsAugust) FROM
(
   ...
   IsAugust = CASE WHEN August=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
   ...
)AS X
GROUP BY...
```

Comment: I think you need `THEN 0 ELSE 1` or `THEN 'FALSE' ELSE 'TRUE'` to get the described output?